# What does Bellman-Ford algorithm detects? Negative weight or negative cycle?

Tags: algorithm, graph

If we are given a graph, Now from source we are to calculate the shortest path. Now , If an edge has a negative weight , but there is  edge to back-edge to get back to that edge while reaching the destination I mean if there is no cycle, then we don't have a negative cycle. But the [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) in Wikipedia the given algorithm which runs from source again thus it detects a negative edge weight but not a negative cycle. My Question is, How to determine a negative cycle?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6919/getting-negative-cycle-using-bellman-ford

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A negative weight cycle is a cycle with weights that sum to a negative number. The Bellman-Ford algorithm propagates correct distance estimates to all nodes in a graph in V-1 steps, unless there is a negative weight cycle. If there is a negative weight cycle, you can go on relaxing its nodes indefinitely. Therefore, the ability to relax an edge after V-1 steps is a test for the presence of a negative weight cycle, as seen in the Wikipedia algorithm. So the Bellman-Ford algorithm tests for negative weight cycles.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this link for determining actual negative cycle.
https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/finding-negative-cycle-in-graph.html
In last iteration of the algo . We only get to know about the effected node .
affected because of negative cycle.
The actual negative cycle forms a infinite loop of parent[parent[parent].

Second loop of the code is like throwing a pinball from the top, after some time the ball revolves around a circular maze infinitely. We find that circular maze.